# Mongodb always start with embedded mode in spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have below in my pom, which i only expect embed mongo db with my unit testing.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But even when i start Spring STS with local mode, the mongo db always start with embeded mode where i can not connect to it using a db client.

For local dev testing, i expect to connect to my local db runs on post 27017 which i mentioned in my application-local.yml as below,

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb
```

This is what my MongoConfig class looks like,

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfig {

    private final MongoProperties mongoProperties;

    public MongoConfig(MongoProperties mongoProperties) {
        super();
        this.mongoProperties = mongoProperties;
    }

    //Other bean initialization methods
}
```

Main class has only @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Can you share your code? Seems everyting is setup correctly. You create new project + add your pom.xml / gradle and debug.

Answer (score 0):

You add following dependency in your pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then add following code in your application.properties file :

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=db_name
```

And you write your model class like :

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "customer")
public class Customer 
{
  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;
  private String mobile;
}
```